# Adding MailGun X-Variables to python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, mailgun

trying to use mailgun's api with the `requests` lib to send emails, tried this

```py
headers ={
        "X-Mailgun-Variables":{
        "email": "joeydanieldarko@gmail.com",
        "another": "kojo_mcroni@hotmail.com"
    }
    }
    send = requests.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.raedarr.com/messages",
                  auth=("api", "key-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                  data={"from": "Raedarr LLC <noreply@raedarr.com>",
                        "template": "verification",
                        "to": ["joeydanieldarko@gmail.com","dlisol@outlook.com" ], "subject": "Hello",
                        # "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
                        },headers=headers)
```

which returns this error message `requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Value for header {X-Mailgun-Variables: {'email': 'joeydanieldarko@gmail.com', 'another': 'kojo_mcroni@hotmail.com'}} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'dict'>`

i then tried this by adding `json.dumps`

```py
headers ={
        "X-Mailgun-Variables":json.dumps({"email":"love@love.com"})
        }
```

this code doesnt throw any error yet i dont see the variable reflecting in my html template, i use `{{ email }}` in my template though